# Unicode character for a space within a word?

Tags: html, text, unicode, localization, word-wrap

Is there a character in unicode for a blank space that would be counted as being in the same word as the characters either side of it?

Example - "This is a **word !**" - where the characters from 'w' through to '!' are counted as part of the same word.

This is causing a particular headache with text wrapping.

EDIT: I'm using createjs, and a typical non-breaking space is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Are you thinking of non-breaking space? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm

Comment: [Unicode spaces](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html)